# looking for way to know through the code which USB device is connected to the machine?

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Path of the USB devices which are connected to the machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4437453/path-of-the-usb-devices-which-are-connected-to-the-machine)

I'm working on a tool which perform different kind of copying - from and to different kind of USB devices, is there any way to know which kind of USB device is connected to my machine through the code?    I need it for the copying path

Comment: Please specify what the desired inputs and outputs to the function you want are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to listen for removable device events and write your code there. i have a post about this here:
[Listen for removable device events](http://alitarhini.wordpress.com/2010/11/05/listen-for-removable-device-events/)

Comment: Do I need different code for each OS?

Comment: I'll ask it more clear- if I have some USB devices wich connected to my machine-  can I know wich path get each one of them?

Comment: yes that's easy. first you remember what drives are already existing on your machine(example: c,d) then when a new usb device is plugged, you get enumerate the hdd again, subtract from original list to get the remaining drive