# C# define USB path

Tags: c#, winforms, path, usb

I need to set default path of USB drive in C# windows application.

I have tried for get application path and Documents path

```
string fileName = @"" + Application.StartupPath + "\\Config1.txt";

string folp = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
```

How to define USB path Like [Application Path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6kObh.png)

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4437453/path-of-the-usb-devices-which-are-connected-to-the-machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4437453/path-of-the-usb-devices-which-are-connected-to-the-machine) Try to check it.

Comment: Thank you this code helps much...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all removable drives, and then get their drive letter like this:

```
 foreach (DriveInfo drive in DriveInfo.GetDrives())
 {
     if (drive.DriveType == DriveType.Removable)
     {
        Console.WriteLine(drive.Name);
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just look for [`DriveType.Removable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.drivetype(v=vs.110).aspx) with [`DriveInfo.GetDrives`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.driveinfo.getdrives(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
var removableDrives = DriveInfo.GetDrives()
                               .Where(x => x.DriveType == DriveType.Removable)
                               .Select(x => x.RootDirectory)
                               .ToList();

if (removableDrives.Any())
{
   string myPath = Path.Combine(removableDrives[0].FullName, "Config1.txt");
}
```

Obviously you have to deal with the case that you have no (or multiple) removable drives, however I'll leave these details up to you.

---

[DriveType Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.drivetype(v=vs.110).aspx)

> **Removable**
>
> The drive is a removable storage device, such as a floppy disk drive
>   or a USB flash drive.

[DriveInfo.GetDrives Method ()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.driveinfo.getdrives(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Retrieves the drive names of all logical drives on a computer
>
> **Remarks**
>
> This method retrieves all logical drive names on a computer. You can
>   use this information to iterate through the array and obtain
>   information on the drives using other DriveInfo methods and
>   properties. Use the IsReady property to test whether a drive is ready
>   because using this method on a drive that is not ready will throw a
>   IOException.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the current directory like so:

```
SetCurrentDirectory("X:\\MyUsbFolder");
```

See [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.setcurrentdirectory%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for details.